# Sortable List function not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I am having a bit of difficulty getting the sortable JQuery function to work in my document.
I would like it to be possible to drag and drop the different assignments between lists, as well as drag assignments from the bottom drawer to above lists.

I apologize for any messy code :/ This is really my first time with HTML,CSS and JQuery

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>navigation template</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var h_bt = 0; //variable to keep track of the div#bottom condition.

    $('a#handler_bottom').on('click', function(event){  

        event.preventDefault();

        if(h_bt == 0){

            //$('div#bottom').animate({top:'600px'}, 300);
            //$('div#top').css({'background-color': 'red'});

            $(this).parent().animate({top:'350px'}, 300);
            $(this).css({'background-color': '#abadb4'});

            h_bt = 1;
        }else{

            $(this).parent().animate({top:'460px'}, 300);
            $(this).css({'background-color': '#abadb4'});

            h_bt = 0;
        }
    });



    var countContents = $('ul#contents li').length;
    var widthContent = $('ul#contents li').width() + 100;

    // stretch the contents width to contain all the <li> element
    $('ul#contents').width(widthContent*countContents);


 $('.move').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var ind = $(this).index();
    var move = -widthContent*ind +"px";
    $('ul#contents').animate({left: move});

}); 
$('ul#menus li').on('click', function(event){
        $('ul#menus li').css({'background-color':'#21253a'});
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#1e1e36'});
});

$('.del').hide();
$(".delete").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.del').show();
});

$(".delete").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.del').hide();
});
 //SORTABLE LISTS
$('.delete').click(function () {
    $(this).parent("li").slideUp(200);
});

('.delete').mouseOver(

function () {
    $('.del').show();
});
$(".connectable_list1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
});
$(".connectable_list2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
});

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
html, body{

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(images/bkgd.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


div#container{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width:980px;
    height:635px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow:hidden; 
}

div#top{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:165px;
    width:815px;
    height:60px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
div#left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:165px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #21253a;
}

div#main{
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
    left:165px;
    width:815px;
    height:700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #E8EBF0;
}

div#bottom{
    position:absolute;
    top:800px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;
}

a#handler_bottom{
    position:absolute; 
    left:375px;
    top:-25px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#menus{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:-50px;

}

#popup{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:160px;
    left:-50px;

}

#popup2{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:349px;
    left:-50px;

}

ul#popup li, ul#popup2 li{
    width:160px;
    padding:20px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}


ul#contents{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul#menus li{
    width:160px;
    padding:20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height:20px;
    background-color: #21253a;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #1e1e36;
    border-top-width: 2px;
}



#menus a:link { 
 color: #929396; 
 text-decoration: none; 
} 

#menus a:visited { 
 color: #929396; 
 text-decoration: none; 
} 

ul#contents{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
}

ul#contents li.content{
    width:815px;
    height:400px;
    left:0;
    padding-right: 105px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.addnew{
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #1e1e36;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

#icon{
    position:absolute;
    width:165px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

#welcome{
    position:absolute;
    width:165px;
    margin-top:30px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#929396;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#caldrop{
    position: absolute;
    left:35px;
    top:18px;
    width:47px;
    height:20px;


}



.delete {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:1%;
}
.delete:hover {
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    width:20%;
}


ul.connectable_list1, ul.connectable_list, ul.headings{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.colcontent {
    width:815px;
    top:40px;
    height:600px;
    left:0;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-color: #e8eaf0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.connectable_list1 {
    /* background:blue;*/
    width:166px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.connectable_list2 {
    /*background:red;*/
    width:800px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    padding-top:30px;
}
.todo {
    clear:both;
}
.asgn {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width:146px;
    height:70px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-top:0px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}


img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin: 0 10px 15px 0;
}

p.title{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    color:#777777;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: "brandon-grotesque",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

p.time{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    top:19px;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #777777;
    font-family: "brandon-grotesque",sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
}

p.location{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 77px;
    top:19px;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: "brandon-grotesque",sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    color: #777777;
}
.td{
   font-family:"Roboto";
    font-weight:300;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width:146px;
    height:60px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
}

img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 15px 0;
}


div#todo{
    position:absolute;
    top:460px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #abadb4;
}
#handler_bottom{
    position:absolute; 
    left:335px;
    top:-22px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #abadb4;
} 


</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top">
            <!--<div id="caldrop"><img height="23" src="images/caldrop.png" width=
            "47"></div>-->
        </div><!--end of div#top-->

        <div id="left">
            <div id="welcome">
                WELCOME, JON
            </div>

            <!--<div id="icon"><img height="62" src="images/jonicon.png" width=
            "62"></div>-->

            <ul id="menus">
                <li class="move">
                    <a href="#">VIEW BY WEEK</a>
                </li>

                <li class="move">
                    <a href="#">VIEW BY CLASS</a>
                </li>

                <li class="addnew">
                    <a href="#">+ ADD NEW</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end of div#top-->

        <div id="main">
            <ul id="contents">
                <li class="content">
                    <div class="colcontent">
                        <ul class="connectable_list1 connectedSortable">
                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#59738a"><a class="del" href=
                                '#'>x</a></span>
                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>
                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>
                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#83403d;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'>x</a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="connectable_list1 connectedSortable">
                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#59738a;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'>x</a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#605d71;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'>x</a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#b0a650;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'></a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="connectable_list1 connectedSortable">
                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#605d71;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'>x</a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#83403d;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'>x</a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#b0a650;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'>x</a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="connectable_list1 connectedSortable">
                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#605d71;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'>x</a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="asgn">
                                <span class='delete' style=
                                "background-color:#b0a650;"><a class="del"
                                href='#'>x</a></span>

                                <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                <p class="time"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                <p class="location"><img src=
                                "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div>
                            <div id="todo">
                                <a href="#" id="handler_bottom"></a>

                                <ul class=
                                "connectable_list2 connectedSortable">
                                    <li class="asgn">
                                        <span class='delete' style=
                                        "background-color:#605d71"><a class=
                                        "del" href='#'>x</a></span>

                                        <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                        <p class="time"><img src=
                                        "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                        <p class="location"><img src=
                                        "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="asgn">
                                        <span class='delete' style=
                                        "background-color:red;"><a class="del"
                                        href='#'>x</a></span>

                                        <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                        <p class="time"><img src=
                                        "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                        <p class="location"><img src=
                                        "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="asgn">
                                        <span class='delete' style=
                                        "background-color:#b0a650;"><a class=
                                        "del" href='#'>x</a></span>

                                        <p class="title">SKETCH IDEATIONS</p>

                                        <p class="time"><img src=
                                        "images/clock.png">10/7</p>

                                        <p class="location"><img src=
                                        "images/clock.png">Home</p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="content">this view shows by week</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end of div#main-->
    </div><!--end of div#container-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code change:

```
('.delete').mouseOver(
```

To:

```
$('.delete').mouseover(
```

It should be working after that. I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs7bv59n/) with your code to check.

---

A note for other question is do not post all your your code in the question, only the part that is causing trouble. And along with that exactly what is not working and an error code if there is one. For example the only way I knew was it said : `undefined not a function` on the line. For example you could of just shown the code:

```
('.delete').mouseOver(

function () {
    $('.del').show();
});
$(".connectable_list1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
});
$(".connectable_list2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
});
```

Along with a maybe a more simple example in HTML and CSS. Most people don't have the time to go through a long code block.